# mariadb master server contains lots (and old) relay log files

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I have a simple master-slave config. For an unknown reason, relay log files are created on the master as well as on the slave server. Everything works fine on the slave and the slave delete relay log files as it go however, since the master is not a slave, I do not understand why relay log files are created there too and these relay log files are never deleted neither.

So, am I missing something?
How to instruct the master to stop creating relay log files?

Mariadb version on these master/slave servers is: 10.0.38-MariaDB

Here is my master server cnf config file:

```
[mysqld]
expire_logs_days=21
innodb_support_xa=1
sync_binlog=1
sync_master_info=1
sync_relay_log=1
sync_relay_log_info=1
binlog_format=mixed
datadir=/data/mysql
max_heap_table_size = 256M
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
net_read_timeout        = 3600
net_write_timeout       = 3600
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 256M
max_connections = 500
table_open_cache = 201000
table_definition_cache = 201000
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 128
query_cache_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G
slave_compressed_protocol = 1
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id       = 1
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you clone the Master from the Slave?  Was there a failover?  Is it "Dual-Master"?

Comment: No. I cloned the slave from the master. The master is not slave of any other server. This is very strange.